# One Production IIS Server ask credentials other accepts windows authentication perfectly

Tags: authentication, iis, server, windows-authentication, credentials

Any advice on troubleshooting Windows Authentication on two production servers.

I have two production IIS servers with windows authentication configured same way but one server handles windows authentication smoothly while other one asks the credentials again and again.

when I run `serverA.website.domain.com` --> it runs perfectly with SSO as well
when I run `serverB.website.domain.com` --> it pops up for windows authentication again and again.

What I have tried :

1. Removed `<deny="*">` from `web.config`
2. make `NTLM` as the top of the providers
3. `Security` tab for published path for `Administrators, System, IIS_WPG, IUSER_MachineName, ASPNET`
4. Added `SERVER$Users` in the Security tab
5. added both the sites --> serverA.website.domain.com & serverB.website.domain.com as `trusted sites` and `intranet sites` and updated `Group policy`

Note: one difference between both the production servers is - `serverA` is the `physical server` where code is published and `serverB` fetches code from shared network via `UNC Share` from `serverA` (kind of virtual server we can say). Not sure if there's any other change needs to be done.

Update: on IE `serverB.website.domain.com` works but on Chrome and Edge it keeps asking for credentials again.
`Fiddler` response for `serverB.website.domain.com` :
[image]

`Fiddler` response for `serverA.website.domain.com` :
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are serverA and serverB under the same demain? You can try to use Network Monitoring to track serverB to see more detailed information.

Comment: yes serverA and serverB - both are on same domain. strange thing is on IE it works but on Chrome and Edge it keeps asking again and again. not sure if UNC share is causing any issue for serverB.

Comment: Clear the browser’s cache and try again, then check the version of Chrome and Edge, it may also be caused by the version.